# AndroidStudio не находит amdvlk64.dll

Tags: java, android

Win 7, AndroidStudio 3.6.2
Написал программку по книжке. Запускаю Run"app". появляется окно "запуск эмулятора", но закрывается и появляется окно, что программа не нашла amdvlk64.dll. Предлагает отослать ошибку разработчику.
Попробовал сам поставить этот файл в винду, перегрузился, но результат тот же.
Подскажите, как с этим бороться?

Comment: помимо добавления файла, возможно требуется регистрация `dll` средствами `regsvr32`

Comment: Попробовал с помощью regsvr32, но получил ответ, что точка входа не найдена. Попробовал скачать из другого источника, тот же результат.

Comment: возможно антивирус заблокировал этот файл.